# get rid of empty spaces, trailing, next line in awk or sed

Tags: json, awk, sed, newline, space

I've got a JSON output which I'd like to modify a bit:

```
JSON={"type":"global", "elements":[
    {"type":"car","model":"bmw", "elements":[
        {"type":"door", "number":"3"},
        {...},
        {...}]
    }]
}
```

I need to put everything in one line:

```
 JSON={"type":"global","elements":[{"type":"car","model":"bmw","elements":[{"type":"door","number":"3"},{...},{...}]}]}
```

I tried this:

```
 JSON=`echo "${JSON}" | nawk  'sub(" *","",$0)'`
```

and  this:

```
 JSON=`echo "${JSON}" | sed  's/^[ \n\t]*//;s/[ \n\t]*$//'`
```

but niether of those helped me, cause the result was:

```
 JSON={"type":"global", "elements":[      <--- the remaining space between key-value groups were also supposed to disappear, but they don't
 {"type":"car","model":"bmw", "elements":[
 {"type":"door", "number":"3"},
 {...},
 {...}]
 }]
 }
```

I would really appreciate if one can help tell me how to get rid of spaces in between the key-value groups as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With awk you can use the OFS and ORS variables

```
awk -v ORS= -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Comment: how can one do it in my way, without 'file' at the end? something like JSON=`echo "${JSON}" | awk  'BEGIN {ORS=""; OFS=""} sub(" *","",$0)'`

Comment: @erikrem: You can do the same with a pipeline: `someprogram | awk -v ORS= -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: @erikrem just pipe: `echo "..." | awk -v ORS= -v OFS= '{$1=$1}1'`. If you don't provide a file to `awk`, it reads from stdin, which is what comes from the previous pipe.

Answer (score 11):

I appear to be a bit late.

Well, for what it's worth, handling JSON with plain-text tools is about as dangerous as handling XML with plain-text tools. In this particular case, you could run into problems when your JSON strings contain spaces, for example.

For this reason, I'd suggest using a JSON-handling tool such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
JSON=$(echo "$JSON" | jq -c .)
```

`jq` parses the JSON properly and takes care to preserve its meaning, so this way the output is guaranteed to have the same meaning as the input.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove them with `tr`:

```
$ tr -d '[\n\t ]' < file
JSON={"type":"global","elements":{"type":"car","model":"bmw","elements":{"type":"door","number":"3"},{...},{...}}}
```

From `man tr`:

> **-d**, --delete
>
> delete characters in SET1, do not translate

Comment: Using tr to remove spaces is "dangerous" in that it will remove spaces within strings, which of course changes the semantics.

Comment: @peak the fact that it is a JSON is irrelevant here, the point is what the OP mentions in the title of the question "get rid of empty spaces, trailing, next line". Otherwise it wouldn't make sense to get rid of all spaces, of course, and your comment would be valid.